# Generating graphics for LaTeX with PyX

Tags: graphics

I have a script from others that uses PyX - Python graphics package to generate graphics for LaTex.

Quoted from http://pyx.sourceforge.net/

> PyX is a Python package for the
>   creation of PostScript and PDF files.
>   It combines an abstraction of the
>   PostScript drawing model with a
>   TeX/LaTeX interface. Complex tasks
>   like 2d and 3d plots in
>   publication-ready quality are built
>   out of these primitives.

1. However its latest news is back at 2007. I was wondering if PyX is still active?
2. If it is one of the best ways to generate graphics for LaTex?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: I am using `matplotlib` for most of my Python scientific graphics. It has nowadays a fairly good Latex interface

Comment: PyX is a wonderful and perfect tool! It doesn't get updates, but that may be because it's so well written!

Comment: "The source code repository has been converted to git and is now hosted at https://github.com/pyx-project/pyx."

Answer (score 5):

One of the more versatile packages for creating all kinds of graphs is [PGF/TikZ](http://www.texample.net/tikz/). There is extensive documentation for it available in the [PDF manual](http://media.texample.net/pgf/builds/pgfmanualCVS2010-09-28.pdf) (note that this is for the CVS version, not for the last release).

I doubt it's very useful for 3D graphics but a special syntax for data visualization ([like here](http://pyx.sourceforge.net/gallery/graphs/index.html)) is currently under development and will be shipped with the next version.

Answer (score 5):

In case you need the interaction with `Python`, it might be worthy to have a look at [PiScript](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~cass/piscript/). AFAIK, the author (Bill Casselman) uses this for the creation of the covers of `AMS Notices`.

Here's an example of a figure produced using PiScript:

[image]